# Автоматизация запуска скрипта Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, архитектура, автоматизация

Я начинающий. Прошу подсказать, каким образом организовать самостоятельный запуск кода? Готов принять совет, ссылку на видео, ссылку на книгу.

Дано:

1. Ко мне подошёл коллега и попросил обработать выгрузку из ИС в виде csv и записать данные в сетевую папку в excel.
2. Коллега будет размещать файл csv в сетевой папке № 1, скрипт будет обрабатывать csv и сохранять в формате excel в папке № 2.
3. Я открыл Jupyter notebook. Написал скрипт, который выполняет все необходимые действия и сохраняет результат в папке № 2.

Вопросы:

1. В каком формате мне сохранить скрипт: .ipynb, .py?
2. Как правильно организовать директорию для подобных скриптов? Представим, что обратилось 10 коллег с разными задачами. Это должна быть папка в "Мои документы" или где? Понимаю, что это должен быть отдельный сервер, который не выключается.
3. Как автоматизировать запуск скрипта? Понимаю, что есть какое-то ПО, которе запускает по расписанию. А как сделать так, чтобы скрипт запускался после того, как в папке № 1 появляется файл, т.е. по триггеру. Или так лучше не делать?
4. Что стоит учесть дополнительно?

Благодарю!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Автоматизация работы скрипта Python.